# Raphael.js path to SVG

Tags: svg, raphael

I have seen SVG images on wikipedia which you can open in notepad and find the code written inside it. My question is if I make a circle in raphael, can I display it as an svg image in the browser?

```
var p = paper.circle(10,10,10).attr({fill:'blue'});
```

then display it as a svg image in my browser. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only work on browsers that support SVG. I think it fails on IE9 too because it doesn't provide support for `.serializeToString()` (though there are shims for this).

```
window.onload = function () {
  var paper = Raphael("container", 100, 100);
  var p = paper.circle(10,10,10).attr({fill:'blue'});
  var textarea = document.getElementById("code")
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  textarea.value = serializer.serializeToString(paper.canvas);
};​
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BvWkU/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {
  var paper = Raphael("container", 100, 100);
  var p = paper.circle(10,10,10).attr({fill:'blue'});
  var textarea = document.getElementById("code")
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  textarea.value = serializer.serializeToString(paper.canvas);
};​
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).